# VBA Filter Unique Values and copy those to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I want to filter unique values form a list and copy paste them to a new sheet. Unfortunately after deleting the new "Tabelle14" to which the filtered data was submitted before ..by doing another conduction with this macro it is impossible because it does not recognize "Tabelle14" anymore. This approach does not work

```
  Sub Makro4()
    '
    ' Makro4 Makro
    '
    ' Tastenkombination: Strg+c
    '
        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        Sheets("Tabelle1").Select
        Columns("K:K").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$K$1:$K$15").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Tabelle14").Select
        Columns("H:H").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    End Sub
```

This was another approach which works much better just by the fact that i do not delete data from the original sheet. What i can not afford is that the data is submitted to another sheet. I tried with `Destination:= instead CopyRange:=` but I don't know how to explain the program to submit something to a new unnamed sheet which is not existing. I also tried by doing something with `Workbooks.Add` and `ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

```
Sub Unique_Values()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("name").Activate
    Range("J:J").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                                CopyToRange:=Range("BO:BO"), _
                                Unique:=True
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you tell us exactly where do the values have to be copied to (column, worksheet name, workbook name)? For example, column `BO` in the first worksheet of a new workbook, or column `BO` in a new worksheet of `ThisWorkbook`...

Comment: Thanks for your request. Same Workbook, just another "unnamed" and "not existing" Sheet which shall be created in the moment when the data is filtered, copied and submitted to the datasheet. For the moment it can be any column on this new datasheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Advanced Filter to a New Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Unique_Values()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        .Parent.Worksheets("name").Range("J:J").AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CopyToRange:=.Range("BO:BO"), _
            Unique:=True
    End With
End Sub

Sub Unique_Values_Worksheet_Variables()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("name")
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    sws.Range("J:J").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=dws.Range("BO:BO"), _
        Unique:=True
End Sub

Sub Unique_Values_Range_Variables()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wb.Worksheets("name").Range("J:J")
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Range("BO:BO")
    srg.AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=drg, _
        Unique:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Many Thanks @VBasic2008....im doing VBA for some weeks now..really no idea how to come up to the idea with "with / end with" same for ".parent." never heared about it.So much to learn. It works perfectly. Do you have any idea or literature or anything else how to improve massively in VBA?  It works quite welll for me doing things in one sheet but as soon as the demand has to work over more than 1 interface (sheets,workbooks, erp, sql etc.) i have a lot of problems.

Comment: It's like a family tree (parent-child analogy): `(Application)`, `Workbook`, `Worksheet`, `Range`. The `Worksheet` is the parent of the `Range`, the `Workbook` is the parent of the `Worksheet`, and the `Application` is the parent of the `Workbook` object. When I want to lookup something, I just google it e.g. `vba parent` or `vba end with`, and mostly pick the `Microsoft Docs` search results: I like to hear it from the 'horse's mouth'. Here's a YouTube video playlist on [Advanced Filter](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7ScsebMq5uV493VqnVEIY35SKxUKwWHM). It's where I learned it.